I haven't granted permission for AWS S3 to the IAM user, but it can still upload files to the bucket
I use GitHub Actions to deploy to AWS Lambda. In my code, I want to upload a file to the S3 bucket 'hello.test.output.data'.
However, I mistakenly wrote 'hello.test.output.data' as 'hello.dev.output.data'. After running the Lambda, I discovered that the file was uploaded to hello.dev.output.data. But the IAM user I utilized in GitHub Actions did not have permission to access hello.dev.output.data.
Therefore, my question is: Is there anything wrong with my settings?
Below is the details of my setting.
Thank you.

I have an IAM user named 'CustomUser-Hello-TEST-GitHubAction'
This IAM user has a policy named 'CustomPolicy-Hello-TEST-S3'.

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::hello.test*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0"
        }
    ]
}


I add .github/workflows/test-pipeline.yml


name: Deploy to TEST
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
  deploy-to-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: test
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      - uses: aws-actions/setup-sam@v2
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_TEST }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_TEST }}
          aws-region: us-east-1

      - run: |
          npm ci
      
      # compile js to ts
      - name: Compile TS
        run: npm run compile

      # copy package.json to built folder for install packages
      - run: cp package.json built/
      - run: cp .npmrc built/

      # sam build 
      - run: sam build --use-container --template template.test.yaml

      # sam deploy
      - run: sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --stack-name Hello-TEST --s3-bucket hello.tmp --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --region us-east-1
  


the template.test.yaml is used in test-pipeline.yml

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
    
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    MemorySize: 1024
    Timeout: 900
    Tags: 
      project: hello
      stage: test

Resources:
  Hello:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./built
      Handler: app.handler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/CustomRole-TEST-Lambda
      FunctionName: Hello-TEST
      Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
        Variables:
          S3_STORAGE_CLASS: STANDARD
          S3_BUCKET_OUTPUT: hello.dev.output.data
          MYSQL_HOST: xxxxxxxx
          MYSQL_DB: xxxxxxxx
          MYSQL_PORT: 3306          
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-xxxxxxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-xxxxxxxx
          - subnet-xxxxxxxx
      Events:
        MySqsEvent:
          Type: SQS # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Queue: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:Hello-TEST-Jobs
            BatchSize: 1
      EventInvokeConfig:
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 0 #Integer (Min: 0, Max: 2)

Is there anything wrong with my settings?

Hi @Shawn,
as far as I can see the data to the bucket is being written by your Lambda function, not by the GitHub Actions job. So you need to check IAM role CustomRole-TEST-Lambda.
